# What patterns should I understand to take advantage of the Android Platform?

Tags: android, design-patterns

what design Pattern used to design the classes of  android API's.Such as Java Swing uses MVC and command pattern, Java RMI uses Proxy pattern,java.awt uses composite pattern,java.util.Calendar uses factory pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you have done some Android application development before, you would find by using Android Binding + MVVM(Model-View-View Model)Pattern, you no longer need to deal with those TextViews, Buttons in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When I do iPhone development I use mostly **Delegator**, so I believe Android has no difference.